# Do I need a script (php) in the server for syncing json data from the server to android app?

Tags: php, android, json, server

I want my android app to communicate with the server (in my case, Godaddy shared server) and sync data in my android app. I want to send and receive JSON data, from the server.

Do I need another PHP script in the server, for this to happen? Is this script necessary in the server to receive my request and give a respond in JSON format?

Comment: Of course you will need server side script

Comment: i tried some tutorials and saw one which uses a url to connect to by using a httprequest. this confused me.

Comment: URL is used to locate resource (your server-side script)

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you want to communicate with server,you must written a backend programmer to deal your request with jsp php or c# and so on